# Orthogonal projection $Id-uu^{t}$ onto $\operatorname{span}(u)^{\perp}$ implies that $Id-2uu^{t}$ reflects about $\operatorname{span}(u)^{\perp}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, orthogonality

In a recent remark in my lecture notes I saw a brief claim that for $u \in \mathbb R^{n}$ the map $Id-2uu^{t}$ reflects points about $\operatorname{span}(u)^{\perp}$ where $\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert_{2}=1$.

As a brief justification for this, it is written that $Id-uu^{t}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}(u)^{\perp}$. Although it is clear that $Id-uu^{t}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}(u)^{\perp}$, why does it immediately follow that $Id-2uu^{t}$ reflects points about $\operatorname{span}(u)^{\perp}$? I may be missing something obvious here.

Comment: As a starting point, what is the result of applying $Id - 2uu^t$ twice?  Geometrically we are saying something about the relationship of vector $v$ and its image $(Id - 2uu^t)v$.

Comment: $(Id-2uu^{t})(Id-2uu^{t})=Id$. True it is involutary

Comment: @hardmath I updated my comment. I still do not see the connection to the map $Id-uu^{t}$ and being an orthogonal projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that the map of vector $v$ to $(I-2uu^t)v$ is symmetric about their midpoint $(I-uu^t)v$.

The fact that this midpoint is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the hyperplane  $\operatorname{span}(u)^\perp$ tells us that $(I-2uu^t)v$ is the "mirror reflection" of  $v$ through this hyperplane.

In addition to verifying the involutary property, you can check that $(I-2uu^t)$ *fixes* points in $\operatorname{span}(u)^\perp$.

Answer (score 2):

Constructively,as you observed, $x_\perp=(I-uu^T)x$ extracts the part perpendicular to $u$. Additionally, $x_\parallel=(uu^T)x$ is the projector to the part parallel to $u$. As the reflection transforms $x=x_\perp+x_\parallel$ into $x_\perp-x_\parallel$, switching the sign in the parallel component, the associated matrix/operator is
$$
(I-uu^T)-(uu^T)=I-2uu^T
$$